Definition of a Smooth Subset
Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $L$ be a holomorphic line bundle on $X$. We assume that there exists a holomorphic line bundle $K$ on $X$ and an isomorphism $K\otimes K\cong L$. Assume we are given a non-zero holomorphic section $\sigma$ of L. We denote $\Sigma \subset L$ the image of $\sigma$. Let $R\subset X$ be the vanishing locus of $\sigma$. With the help of local trivializations of $L$, $R$ is locally defined by one holomorphic equation.
The exercise is to show that $Y:=\phi^{-1}(\Sigma)$ is smooth if and only if $R$ is smooth.
What is meant by smooth here? I know that $R$ is a subset of our manifold $X$, is it asking us to show that $R$ inherits the structure of a smooth manifold with the subspace topology? $\phi:K\to L$ is defined by $(x,\tau)\mapsto (x,\tau^{2})$.

$Y$ is a branched double cover of $\Sigma$ branched along $R$. I assume that by smooth they mean that it is going to be a smooth complex submanifold, yes.
